# Install Mono ASP.NET on debian

Tags: debian, .net, mono

I've been trying to install mono ASP.NET onto my debian VPS and I am unable to do so.

I know I need mono which can support .NET 4.0 now.

I am unsure if I need XSP **and** mod_mono, or just mod_mono. The link http://mono-project.com/Mod_mono says I do, but other sources say I don't. And now I'm not sure. And on another website I saw that XSP2 exists, and XSP doesn't support .NET 4.0. I'm really not sure anymore!

Is there a way to set this up within debian so I can run C# .NET code?

Edit:

I'm told that xsp is dep for mod_mono ? And it's already part of it maybe?

Comment: Do you want ASP or ASP.Net?

Comment: @Tokk ASP.Net so i can use aspx and C#

Answer (score 2):

The simple part is

```
sudo apt-get install libapache2-mod-mono
```

It will get you the dependencies.

The tricky part is configuring your virtual hosts and integrate that with mod_mono's registered sites. Somehow in Debian there is going to be a directory under /etc (/etc/mono-apache-server?) with a file which you need to edit. This file looks a lot like an xsp2 config file (but XSP2 is not launched, but mono-apache-server2 depends on xsp2-core).

There are numerous resources on the web that try to guide you, but anytime I configured it I spent around an hour getting things right, and I never really got out of the 'confused' state.

Good luck

Comment: Got it. Also note I edited /etc/apache2/mods-available/mod_mono.conf
 and added  MonoAutoApplication enabled MonoServerPath “/usr/bin/mod-mono-server2″ to the bottom to make it work through the browser